# Is it possible to change Drupal8 admin password using Drush?

Tags: drupal, command-line, drupal-8, drush

Is it possible to change Drupal8 admin password using  Drush? Or fetch the password in any other way.

I have forgot the administrator password for the local Site. I can access the database and also able to access the user related table. As in my localhost there is no smtp server setup I am unable to get email using forget password.

If anyone have any idea to fetch the password or reset it, thus I could able to use the password. Please let me help with your valuable suggestions.

Comment: I have got a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried several time the flood table got several records and blocked the user.
To clear the data and unblock the user I have used the following drush command

```
drush sqlq "DELETE FROM flood"
```

Then I had run the following command to reset password

```
drush upwd --password="mypassword" "admin"
```

After that I was able to login into the site.

I got some help from drupal community and the following post [Recovering the administrator password](https://www.drupal.org/node/44164)

Answer (score 1):

On Drupal 8 you can do this :

```
drush upwd my_username my_password
# drush upwd admin 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

i know you found a solution to your issue but for future reference and anyone else that may stumble upon this. Drush can provide a one time login for superuser.

```
drush uli
```

after that you can copy and paste the link into your browser.

documentation here: https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/user/user-login/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this. It was in the [ https://www.drupal.org/node/44164 ] (Documentation) but somehow was not working for me. After that I found that solution and also added to the documentation.

Comment: understood. Curious to know why that didn't work though.

Comment: I tried several time with wrong password and drupal locked the user access. This might be a reason.